# An embedded function block outputs scalar values for each input, how three or more sequential outputs can be stored and compared?

Tags: matlab, vector

I tried using if else statement, but yielded no result.  Can this be done by connecting program block and simulink blocks?

simple block dia

solarmodule--(power)-->controller---(dutycycle)-->converter-->load

power from solar module is a scalar varying,i m sending three dutycycles(d1 d2 d3) one by one, simultaneously corresponding power P1 P2 P3 should be sensed. i wanna concatenateP=[ P1 P2 P3 ], ........P is given embedded fcn block2(Particle swarm optimizer controller) for further processing.

Comment: Could you provide some of the code you've tried? Also, please provide some examples of your inputs.

Comment: my coding is very lengthy...soon i will post, I have edited my question explaining my model..

Comment: i have given how i m giving inputs, now i m trying to store the continuous data as vector using 'zero order hold' and 'delay elements', how to send multiple inputs to one terminal sequentially one after other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save multiple scalar answers in matlab the answer is typically to store them in a vector.

Suppose you want to store the i-th scalar output, then you just need something like

```
A(i) = yourscalaroutput
```

Comment: to dennis,  my solar module gives different scalar power output for different dutycycles , where duty cycle is input to another block(power converter),

 my algorithm sends three duty cycles ,corresponding real time scalar power need to concatenated and given as input to PSO controller, concatenation should be done during simulation

how this can be done

Comment: if you have a scalar input and want to concatenate it with anotherone you can do:

existingvector = [existingvector scalartobeadded]

Comment: in my program existingvector scalartobeadded has the same variable name. but the value in the variable changes. It is something to do with sample time.Give suggestions for this case if any..